# Tricks to improve the performance of a cunstom function in Julia

Tags: performance, matlab, julia

I am replicating using Julia a sequence of steps originally made in Matlab. In Octave, this procedure takes 1.4582 seconds and in Julia (using Jupyter) it takes approximately 10 seconds. I'll try to be brief in the scripts. My goal is to achieve or improve Octave's performance. First of all, I will describe my variables and some function:

1. zgrid (double 1x7 size)
2. kgrid (double 500x1 size)
3. V0 (double 500x7 size)
4. P (double 7x7 size) a transition matrix
5. delta and beta are fixed parameters.
6. F(z,k) and u(c) are particular functions and are specified in the Julia script.

```
% Octave script
% V0 is given
[K, Z, K2] = meshgrid(kgrid, zgrid, kgrid);
K = permute(K, [2, 1, 3]);
Z = permute(Z, [2, 1, 3]);
K2 = permute(K2, [2, 1, 3]);

C = max(f(Z,K) + (1-delta)*K - K2,0);
U = u(C);

EV = V0*P';% EV is a 500x7 matrix size
EV = permute(repmat(EV, 1, 1, 500), [3, 2, 1]);
H = U + beta*EV;
[TV, index] = max(H, [], 3);
```

In Julia, I created a function that replicates this procedure. I used loops, but it has a performance 9 times longer.

```
% Julia script
% V0 is the input of my T operator function
V0 = repeat(sqrt.(kgrid), outer = [1,7]);
F = (z,k) ->  exp(z)*(k^α);
u = (c) -> (c^(1-μ) - 1)/(1-μ)

% parameters
α = 1/3
β = 0.987
δ = 0.012;
μ = 2
Kss = 48.1905148382166
kgrid = range(0.75*Kss, stop=1.25*Kss, length=500);
zgrid = [-0.06725382459813659, -0.044835883065424395, -0.0224179415327122, 0 , 0.022417941532712187, 0.04483588306542438, 0.06725382459813657]

function T(V)
    E=V*P'
    T1 = zeros(Float64, 500, 7 )
    aux = zeros(Float64, 500)
    for i = 1:7
        for j = 1:500
            for l = 1:500
                c= maximum( (F(zrid[i],kgrid[j]) +(1-δ)*kgrid[j] - kgrid[l],0))
                aux[l] =  u(c) + β*E[l,i]
            end
            T1[j,i] = maximum(aux)     
        end
    end
    return T1
end
```

I would very much like to improve my performance in Julia. I believe there is a way to improve, but I am new in Julia programming.

Comment: your Julia code has a bug. The parentheses don't match

Comment: Also, why does `aux` have length `5000` when you appear to only be accessing the first `500` elements of it?

Comment: Also, where are `kgrid` and `zrid` defined?

Comment: If they are `global` variables, that might be part of the problem

Comment: Fixed the bug and the limit 5000. kgrid is something like range(0.75*Kss, stop=1.25*Kss, length=500) where Kss = 48.1905148382166. The zgrid is a discretization of an AR(1) via Tauchem method.

Comment: zgrid = [-0.06725382459813659,
 -0.044835883065424395,
 -0.0224179415327122,
 -6.938893903907228e-18,
  0.022417941532712187,
  0.04483588306542438,
  0.06725382459813657]

Comment: Do you think I should edit my question by putting these variables explicit?

Comment: The u and F functions depend on other calibration parameters. In order not to load the script, I decided not to specify them completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code runs for me in 5ms. Note that I have made `F` and `u` into proper (not anonymous) functions, `F_` and `u_`, but you could get a similar effect by making the anonymous functions `const`.

Your main problem is that you have a lot of non-`const` global variables, and also that your main function is doing unnecessary work multiple times, and creating an unnecessary array, `aux`.

The performance tips section in the manual is essential reading: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/

```
F_(z,k) = exp(z) * (k^(1/3));  # you can still use α, but it must be const
u_(c) = (c^(1-2) - 1)/(1-2)

function T_(V, P, kgrid, zgrid, β, δ)
    E = V * P'
    T1 = similar(V)
    for i in axes(T1, 2)
        for j in axes(T1, 1)
            temp = F_(zgrid[i], kgrid[j]) + (1-δ)*kgrid[j]
            aux = -Inf
            for l in eachindex(kgrid)
                c = max(0.0, temp - kgrid[l])
                aux = max(aux, u_(c) + β * E[l, i])
            end
            T1[j,i] = aux
        end
    end
    return T1
end
```

Benchmark:

```
V0 = repeat(sqrt.(kgrid), outer = [1,7]);
zgrid = sort!(rand(1, 7); dims=2)
kgrid = sort!(rand(500, 1); dims=1)
P = rand(length(zgrid), length(zgrid))
@btime T_($V0, $P, $kgrid, $zgrid, $β, $δ);
# output:   5.126 ms (4 allocations: 54.91 KiB)
```

Comment: It is an excellent solution. Now I'm trying to iterate the T_ function, but I'm doing something wrong. First I declare a certain tolerance 'tol' and I set dist = tol +1. So, While dist> tolerance, do V1 = T_ (V0); dist = distance(V1, V0); V0 = V1. But this takes too long. I think the solution to this new problem is to add a while loop and adapt the code above. Do you think I should create a new question? I've been thinking all day and I can't optimize. My distante function is:  maximum(abs.(V1 - V0)).

Comment: Not sure why this would take long, but make sure that you are avoiding globals, wrap the outer loop in a function, pass variables as input arguments, and read the performance tips thoroughly. If it's still slow, I would open a new question. (Your distance function can be sped up, too. Use `abs2` instead of `abs`, and put a dot on the minus sign as well. It would be even faster if you avoid allocating the temporary array.)

Comment: I think I am repeating operations within the while loop. I created a new question by placing the Matlab version. You can clearly see that the Matab version avoids operations in the while loop. The link is this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66937910/iterating-a-custom-function-efficiently-in-julia

Answer (score 2):

The following should perform much better. The most noticeable differences are that it calculates `F` 500x less, and doesn't rely on global variables.

```
function T(V,kgrid,zgrid,β,δ)
    E=V*P'
    T1 = zeros(Float64, 500, 7)
    for j = 1:500
        for i = 1:7
            x = F(zrid[i],kgrid[j]) +(1-δ)*kgrid[j] 
            T1[j,i] = maximum(u(max(x - kgrid[l], 0)) + β*E[l,i] for l in 1:500)
        end
    end
    return T1
end
```

Comment: This procedure took 4.017568 seconds. Matlab took 1.4582 seconds. Do you think it's because I'm using Jupyter?

Comment: No. It's probably some combination of the implementation of `u`, and `F`.

Comment: Also possibly type stability issues

Comment: @Fam: the big difference is that in MATLAB you call `f` once, in the Julia code it is called 500x7 times. The function call overhead is likely the deciding factor here.

Comment: matlab is calling the function once on a 500x7 array, which should be about the same as Julia where it's being called 500x7 times on a single value.